# Unusual Message Source Name in SSIS standard Report

Tags: ssis, connection-string

Usually, in a dtsx Standard Report, there is a column "Message Source Name" that indicates which dtsx threw the error or raised the event.

Now i get "Transact-SQL stored procedure" and of course I don't have such a dtsx.

So, question #1 is: **Where should I go to check the error?**

Besides, the error is: An error occurred while setting the value of a property "InitialCatalog". The error returned is 0x80020009. The connection string components cannot contain unquoted semicolons....

My dtsx were doing fine and I was publishing dtsx on a regular basis with no problems. Then, I changed the name of a ConnectionManager and took care of changing this name wherever it appeared.
After this fateful move, I cannot manage to restore the previous situation. Even rollbacking all changes through TFS and going back to the previous names doesn't solve the matter.
I checked also the environment I am using and the configuration of the job that launches the dtsx, to no avail.

If I execute the dtsx on my development machine, from visual studio, it works fine. The problem arises in production enviroment when I use the job configured with the environment. In the project configuration and in the environment configuration I don't see what an "unquoted semicolumn" could be.

The value of the connection string that is indicated as having an error looks like:

Data Source=11.1.1.11,1111;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; Integrated Security=SSPI ;Auto Translate=False;

Question #2 is: **Where could this connection string with unquoted semicolon be?**

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

With much effort I managed to find an answer to Question #2:

I am using parametrized connection managers, so I have a project parameter (let's call it PP1) in my dtsx with the connString.

During configuration of the SSIS project I need to give a value ONLY for the parameter PP1, and NOT for the connection string.

What I did wrong was to give the Environment Variable with the connString to the Property "Initial Catalog". Therefore, SSIS was lamenting of the presence of ";" (the ones in the connString) in the InitialCatalog.